# What is the GNOME equivalent to Side Stage?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, window-manager, gnome-shell

One feature of Unity 8 / Ubuntu Touch that I was looking forward to seeing on the desktop was Side Stage, which allowed you to put "a phone-sized application on one side [of the screen] and a tablet-sized application on the other" [(Ars Technica)](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/02/shuttleworth-ubuntu-tablets-wont-be-as-jarring-to-users-as-windows-8/2/).

[image: Side Stage demonstration from Canonical]

Is there a GNOME Shell feature or extension to dock an application to the side of the screen in a similar way? Note that the right-hand application is slimmer (not equal width), and is docked permanently (other windows adjust themselves to fit) -- so it's not the same as just snapping left and right.

Comment: might be relevant http://gfxmonk.net/shellshape/

Answer (score 0):

Pop-Shellhttps://github.com/pop-os/shell allows this, though not automatically.

If you align two windows side by side, you can then resize them until they are just like this.